# how to partially replace data of a column using another date column in R

Tags: r

I have a sample dataset  as shown below

```
sampDate <- as.Date(c("2011-09-01","2011-09-02","2011-09-03","2011-09-04","2011-09-05", "2011-09-06"), format ="%Y-%m-%d")

p1 <- c( 10,  6.1, 11.1,  9.1,  10.1, 7)
p2 <- rep(1,6)

df <- data.frame(sampDate,p1,p2);df

    sampDate   p1  p2
1 2011-09-01 10.0  1
2 2011-09-02  6.1  1
3 2011-09-03 11.1  1
4 2011-09-04  9.1  1
5 2011-09-05 10.1  1
6 2011-09-06  7.0  1
```

I'd like to replace the 1's in column p2, which are from date 2011-09-01 till 2011-09-03, with zeros instead, so that the resulting dataframe will be like this;

```
    sampDate   p1  p2
1 2011-09-01 10.0  0
2 2011-09-02  6.1  0
3 2011-09-03 11.1  0
4 2011-09-04  9.1  1
5 2011-09-05 10.1  1
6 2011-09-06  7.0  1
```

I have been trying to use `ifelse` and other indexing operators but i'm just running into a brick wall. If i would get an indexing method, it would be the best because of my large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

```
within(df, p2 <- replace(p2, sampDate>="2011-09-01" & sampDate<="2011-09-03", 0))
```

will do the trick.

```
    sampDate   p1 p2
1 2011-09-01 10.0  0
2 2011-09-02  6.1  0
3 2011-09-03 11.1  0
4 2011-09-04  9.1  1
5 2011-09-05 10.1  1
6 2011-09-06  7.0  1
```

Comment: wow danke Sven! Simple and neat. Did'nt even know function "within" existed. Thanks alot for the enlightenment

Comment: @kigode, if Sven's recommendation helps you with your problem or answers your question, don't forget to upvote or mark the answer as accepted. That helps keep the "unanswered" queue in the R tag more manageable ;)

Comment: The legibility of this answer is nice (not unnecessarily repeating `df` and so on). However, basic subsetting and replacement *might* be faster: `df[df$sampDate >= "2011-09-01" & df$sampDate <= "2011-09-03", "p2"] <- 0`

Comment: @mrdwab, thanks, and noted. But i couldn't upvote it since i'm new and i don't have the threshold reputation to do that.